# Slide div from left to right in Angular

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4SGU7sDV38xH4HqK3eh?p=preview) I have a div that should move from left to right in a transition when the user clicks on the checkbox. Instead, the div just hides and shows in the new position. How to achieve the transition effect in Angular?

HTML:

```
Move <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" />
<div class="panel" ng-class="{ 'class1' : checked, 'class2' : !checked }"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel{
  position: fixed;
  background:orange;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  top: 10px;
}

.class1{
  left: 80px;
}

.class2{
  left: 240px;
}


.class1.ng-show-add-active, .class1.ng-show-remove-active {
transition: all ease-in-out 2s;
}


.class2.ng-show-add-active, .class2.ng-show-remove-active {
transition: all ease-in-out 2s;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('ctl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: you need to use key frame animations or js to do that type of animation. Means that when the input is checked it would trigger a key frame animation to increase the left value 1 px at a time over a certain time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer: you need to use `-add` and `-remove` after the class name.

[PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/bvQV589Ag7JNzLbkycin?p=preview)